# Why are global constraints so ineffective?

Tags: c++, physics, physics-engine, joints

There are two objects here, each with 3 constraint points.

I use formula:
$$
\lambda=(JM^{-1}J^{T})^{-1}(-JV-b)
$$
$$
\Delta V=M^{-1}J^{T}\lambda \
$$

I put the information of the three constraint points (normals, constraint point radius) into the formula to calculate.

But the result was not ideal. Instead of shortening the distance between the three constraint points, it became farther.

I don’t want to use iterative calculation. I have used iterative calculation. It needs to be iterated 10000+ times to get better results. This is too slow.

Is there any good solution?